# Sorting a range in Excel VBA before copying the range to a Visio sheet (Error 1004)

Tags: excel, vba, visio

I have one Excel and one Visio file, both have data generated with VBA. The goal is to automate the table sorting.

A range is created and filled with data, including differing headers. There's a large header on top which is also changing with each dataset.

The table is looking like this:

| Priority1 | IrrelevantData | Priority2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B2 | irrelevant stuff | B |
| A1 | irrelevant stuff | A |
| B1 | irrelevant stuff | A |
| A2 | irrelevant stuff | B |

And should look like this:

| Priority1 | IrrelevantData | Priority2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | irrelevant stuff | A |
| A2 | irrelevant stuff | B |
| B1 | irrelevant stuff | A |
| B2 | irrelevant stuff | B |

So far, to do this for the specified range only would be to apply a `.Sort` on the specified range. But in doing so, I run into the `Error 1004` saying that there's either a missing range or a missing name.

```
For i = 1 To entriesToBeGenerated
    With xlWB_Vis.Sheets(1)
        Set xlRngVis = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(20, 4)) ' setting range, working as intended
    End With
    ReDim Vis_Array(1 To 20, 4) ' redefine array, working as intended
            
    For k = 1 To 20
        ' write values to array; this is working properly and as intended
    Next k
    ' next line --> Error 1004
    xlRngVis.Sort key1:=Range("A3"), Header:=xlYes, key2:=Range("C3"), order1:=xlAscending, order2:=xlAscending 
    xlRngVis.Copy ' copy is working as intended
    vsoPage.PasteSpecial 49162, False, False   '49162 = Excel Worksheet
    ' vsoPage.PasteSpecial is working as intended as well. only '.Sort' doesn't work
Next i
```

From what I've gathered, I assume there's an issue with the selected range that it somehow isn't registered properly; but this has me confused as it's clearly copying the (unsorted) table correctly if I remove the `.Sort`.

By changing the latter part to

```
    With xlWB_Vis.Sheets(1)
        xlRngVis.Sort key1:=.Range("A3"), Header:=xlYes, key2:=.Range("C3"), order1:=xlAscending, order2:=xlAscending
    End With
```

I managed to sort the first generated table with it, but the second table is not generating anymore because the `.Sort` is not following the selected data (according to the error), meaning I'd have to shift the `.Sort`-Range alongside.

My solution was to just add the cell ranges with `.Range(.Cells(3, 1 + ((i - 1) * 4))), key2:=.Range(.Cells(3, (3 + ((i - 1) * 4))` (Basically choosing "A3" & "C3" as starting points and then moving forward to "E3" and "G3". At least that was the idea.) ... which is met with a **generic 1004 Error**.

Any help would be much appreciated. I know that this isn't the prettiest of implementations.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it (and I want to scream), thus [answering myself](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) here. It's a **syntax error**.

The proper syntax is **not** `key2:=.Range(.Cells(3, (3 + ((i - 1) * 4))` **but instead just** `key2:=.Cells(3, (3 + ((i - 1) * 4)`.

The reason being why it works with `.Range("A3")` and *not* `.Range(.Cells(...))` seems to be that `.Cells(...)` is identical in function to `.Range("A3")`, which is only really making sense in hindsight. So, basically, all you need to define is one single cell. Anyway, thank you for coming to my SO talk.

It can be made more structurally sound by also changing `xlRngVis.Sort` to `xlRngVis.CurrentRegion.Sort`.